# What kind of display/device has a resolution 1045x627?

Tags: resolution

I was looking through the google analytics for my site and noticed a rather odd resolution.
Any idea what sort of device might use such a resolution?

Comment: The ratio is 1.66666... recurring. I don't know if that's significant.

Answer (score 2):

Can you get the browser type? That would help narrow it down a lot. I came across this before in log files and the reported software was Netscape 5.0 on Windows 3.1.

I don't think this has ever been a standard resolution on Windows so it may have been running in a virtual environment of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Netbook comes to mind. Also, you can set your card/monitor to odd sizes sometimes. And as someone else said, it could also be a virtual environment. It is also possible that the resolution was detected incorrectly.

Note that available resolutions is up to the video card drivers, and NOT Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Internet kiosks in shopping malls and airports also come to mind as devices with odd screen resolutions.